# Filter out result from Map with multiple conditions

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have a Map with list of `empid` and `name`. I want to select only `emp name` of people whose `id` is greater than 7 and name starts with N.
The result must be SET.

I tried using `map.entryset()` but cannot think how to filter inside map.

Do we have to use if else?
 How we will return to set if multiple elements are found?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: If you want to use if/else, you will need to do it inside a for loop that iterates over the values of the map, storing those which match your criteria in a result set or map. A more modern alternative would be to use a stream, but if you're not familiar with them I think you shouldn't bother before you've got a working solution.

Comment: Cant we use for loop?? Why everyone is using stream?

Comment: @mukka because its tag with java8 too .Also can you define your map ?

Comment: @mukka please show the declaration of the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<Integer, String> nameMap = new HashMap<>(); //A dummy map with empid and name of emp
public static void main(String[] args) {
    nameMap.put(1,"John");
    nameMap.put(2,"Doe");
    nameMap.put(37,"Neon");
    nameMap.put(14,"Shaun");
    nameMap.put(35,"Jason");
    nameMap.put(0,"NEO");
    Set<String> empSet = nameMap.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(x->x.getKey()>7 && x.getValue().startsWith("N"))
                        .map(x->x.getValue())
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    empSet.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

> The actual implementation and namespaces will vary but the basic
>   operations will remain same.

Comment: even StackOverflow indicates poor naming styles, for e.g. look at your variable name and compare it with the class name `Map`, `Integer` etc. Use lower case in variable names.

Comment: @nullpointer , ok man, i edited it, but all indent is now hapazard, any shortcut to make code align now here??

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @CommonMan I've edited the answer for the formatting and raw type comment as well. You can possibly figure that one out in the last edit made by me.

Comment: @nullpointer , i am still learning by seeing your all answers, but how do correct alignment when you copy paste your code from IDE to here , think like you have edited here and now your alignment is destroyed and your code looks really big and ugly?? Do you copy back the code to IDE and then align it and again paste it here or what??

Comment: Thankks @Lino as always :)

Answer (score 3):

It should be something like this,

```
Set<String> selectedEmps = empIdToName.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey() > 7)
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().startsWith("N"))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: is there any disadvantage if we use `.filter(e -> e.getKey() > 7)
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().startsWith("N"))` in same filter with `&&` operator?? any performance issue?

Comment: I think both approaches are more or less the same. I have no idea on how the runtime optimizes it though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, here's a solution:
Suppose we have this data:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("Noo", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8,8,9)));
map.put("No", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,8,9)));
map.put("Aoo", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8,8,9)));
```

We can filter the data in this way:

```
map.entrySet().
            stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith("N"))
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().filter(id -> id <= 7).findAny().orElse(0) == 0)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The first filter excludes the Names that does not start with `"N"`, the second filter goes through the remaining entries and check if all their `ids` are greater than 7. In the foreach I just print the data, but you can change the logic to your needs

The result should the this:

```
Noo [8, 8, 9]
```

Comment: i think op asked for the result to be in set :P

Comment: use `filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(id -> id <= 7))` instead of `filter()` + `findAny()`

Answer (score 1):

Can be done very easily with a simple for-loop:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = ...
Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getKey() > 7){
        String name = entry.getValue();
        if(name.charAt(0) == 'N'){
            result.add(name);
        }
    }
}
```

*Note*: if the names can be empty (`length() == 0`) then the `name.charAt(0)` approach will not work as you'll get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: He refered to his sentence : ``I have a Map with list of empid and name``. I also understand that the input should be in this form ``Map<String, List<Integer>>``

Comment: Still i'm not sure honesty ,OP should define map atleast .

Comment: classic approach.